# Call shell with spaces in file path

Tags: shell, vba, zip, unzip

The code below unzips a .zip file using winzip. However, if the FolderPath contains a blank, I get non-trappable error "Failed to open document.", without an error number. How can I unzip this file with Shell if the FolderPath contains a blank? Thank you,

```
 FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

 Unzipfile = Dir(FolderPath & "*.zip")
 While UnzipFile <> ""
 if InStr(1, UnzipFile, ".zip") > 0 Then
 ShellStr = "C:\Program Files\WinZip\winzip32 e- " & FolderPath & UnzipFile & " " & FolderPath
 Call Shell(ShellStr, vbHide)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote paths with spaces

```
ShellStr = """C:\Program Files\WinZip\winzip32.exe"" e- """ & _
            FolderPath & UnzipFile & """ """ & FolderPath & """"
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I'd l already tried your suggestion and whilst it calls the files successfully, it unzips them in a new folder called 'New'. The file name has the string '.../New Folder/' so the gap is between 'New' and 'Folder. Would you know how I can ensure that they unzip in 'New Folder'? Thanks.

Comment: Quoting the path is the typical approach here - I'm not aware of any other way to deal with spaces in paths (other than don't use them!). See my edit above though - forgot the leading quote in the destination folder path.